# Redirect stdout while a process is running -- What is that process sending to /dev/null

Tags: linux, bash, operating-systems

I've run a command and redirected it's output via `> /dev/null`
Now that it's been running significantly longer than I expected I want to see what it's doing.

Is there a way to re-redirect the output, such that all the new contents would be printed to `stdout`? I realize that all the previous contents are gone.

Comment: +1 good question, I would have thought you could be something with /proc/<pid>/fd/1 but it did not work for me.

Comment: What OS? assuming Gnu/Linux.

Comment: Yeah, Ubuntu in particular

Comment: Maybe [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249703/how-can-a-process-intercept-stdout-and-stderr-of-another-process-on-linux) work for you? Slightly different situation though.

Comment: Daniel, thanks. Not sure if it works after the output has been redirected, but I'll try it and let you know!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You can do it using strace.**

Using `strace` you can spy what is being written to file-descriptor 1, which is the stdout file descriptor. Here is an example:

```
strace  -p $pid_of_process_you_want_to_see_stdout_of 2>&1 | \
    sed -re 's%^write\(1,[[:blank:]](.*),[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+\)[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+%\1%g'
```

You may want to improve the filter, but that would be another question. We have the output, but now need to tidy it.

:WARNING: This solution has some limitations, see comments below. It will not always work, your mileage may vary.

**Test:**

Put this program (below) in file `hello`, and `chmod +x hello`

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    echo -en  "hello\nworld\n"
done
```

This one in `hello1` and `chmod +x hello1`

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(dirname $0)
$dir/hello >/dev/null
```

This one in `hello2` and `chmod +x hello2`

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(dirname $0)
$dir/hello1 >/dev/null
```

then run with `./hello2 >/dev/null`,
then find pid of process hello and type `pid_of_process_you_want_to_see_stdout_of=xyz` where xyz is the pid of hello,
then run line at top.

How it works.
When hello is run, bash forks, redirects fd 1 to `/dev/null`, then execs hello.
Hello sends output to fd1 using system call `write(1, …`.
Kernel receives system call `write(1, …`, sees that fd 1 is connected to `/dev/null` and …

We then run strace (system-call trace) on hello, and see that it is calling `write(1, "hello\nworld\n")`
The rest if the line above is just selecting the appropriate line of the trace.

Comment: Won't work if the child spawns its own children.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, I have now added test for when child spawns its own child. Test Passed.

Comment: Still broken.  If the child spawns lots of children that come and go or if several grandchildren are running concurrently, this doesn't capture them all.  Also, this fails if any of the children or grandchildren dup the handle.  I explained these were problems above before you insisted you had a solution; I'm surprised you didn't think about this.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, if it is a choice between a 90% solution and no solution then which one should I choose? Now I understand that if the program is made up of lots of short lived children that are doing the output then this wont work as is. ( we would have to strace all ancestors of pid, and try to make sense of it. But what about dup, that would change the system call from `write(', … to write(n,… and we have to discover n. Still not impossible, we have to consider how important this data is and how much time to spend trying to get it.

Comment: Worthy of thumbs up, and answers the OP.

Comment: Also it is worth to note that strace automatically truncates output to 32 chars, one can use -s parameter to change it.

Comment: What’s the benefit of having `hello2` call `hello1` which calls `hello`?  And what’s the point of redirecting stdout to `/dev/null` twice?

Comment: @Scott, as can be seen from earlier comment, there was a concern about weather the solution would work if a process spawned a child, that spawned a child. So there is no advantage, it just tests that it works.

Comment: Ah, I may have misread your answer yesterday. I see now that you’re saying “run `hello2`, which calls `hello1`, which calls `hello`, *and then **find the PID of the* `hello` *process (i.e., the child of the child)** and run the `strace` command against that PID.*”  I agree with @NicoleHamilton — you have not addressed her comment, which is that, if you apply your command to a process *that has already spawned children,* it won’t capture the output of the children. Modifying your answer to apply the `strace` command ***to the grandchild process*** is doing an end-around on her issue. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  P.S. If the `hello` script said `echo … > /dev/null`, your solution would fail.  I concede that it would be just about impossible to handle that situation, and I realize that you admit ***(in a comment)*** that you have presented only a 90% solution.  But it would be better to disclose the constraints and limitations of your answer ***in the answer**.*

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the answer to this question quite a long time. There are mainly two solutions available:

1. As You stated here, strace option;
2. Getting the output using gdb.

In my case none of them was saisfactory, because first truncates the output (and I couldn't set it longer). The second is out of question, since my platform doesn't have gdb installed - it's an embedded device.

Collecting some partial information on the Internet (didn't created it, just put pieces together), I reached the solution using named pipes (FIFOs). When the process is run, its output is directed to the named pipe and if no one wants to see it, a dumb listener (tail -f  >> /dev/null) is applied to it to empty the buffer. When someone wants to get this output, the tail process is killed (otherwise the output is alternated between readers) and I cat the pipe. On listening finish, another tail starts up.

So my problem was to start a process, exit the ssh shell, and then log once again and be able to get the output. This is doeable now with following commands:

```
#start the process in the first shell
./runner.sh start "<process-name-with-parameters>"&
#exit the shell
exit

#start listening in the other shell
./runner listen "<process-name-params-not-required>"
#
#here comes the output
#
^C

#listening finished. If needed process may be terminated - scripts ensures the clean up
./runner.sh stop "<process-name-params-not-required>"
```

The script which accomplish that is attached below. I am aware of that it's not a perfect solution. Please, share Your thoughts, maybe it will be helpful.

```
#!/bin/sh

## trapping functions
trap_with_arg() {
    func="$1" ; shift
    for sig ; do
        trap "$func $sig" "$sig"
    done
}

proc_pipe_name() {
    local proc=$1;
    local pName=/tmp/kfifo_$(basename ${proc%%\ *});
    echo $pName;
}

listener_cmd="tail -f";
func_start_dummy_pipe_listener() {
    echo "Starting dummy reader";
    $listener_cmd $pipeName >> /dev/null&
}

func_stop_dummy_pipe_listener() {
    tailPid=$(func_get_proc_pids "$listener_cmd $pipeName");
    for pid in $tailPid; do
        echo "Killing proc: $pid";
        kill $tailPid;
    done;
}

func_on_stop() {
        echo "Signal $1 trapped. Stopping command and cleaning up";
    if [ -p "$pipeName" ]; then
        echo "$pipeName existed, deleting it";
        rm $pipeName;
    fi;



    echo "Cleaning done!";
}

func_start_proc() {
    echo "Something here"
    if [ -p $pipeName ]; then
        echo "Pipe $pipeName exists, delete it..";
        rm $pipeName;
    fi;
    mkfifo $pipeName;

    echo "Trapping INT TERM & EXIT";
    #trap exit to do some cleanup
    trap_with_arg func_on_stop INT TERM EXIT

    echo "Starting listener";
    #start pipe reader cleaning the pipe
    func_start_dummy_pipe_listener;

    echo "Process about to be started. Streaming to $pipeName";
    #thanks to this hack, the process doesn't  block on the pipe w/o readers
    exec 5<>$pipeName
    $1 >&5 2>&1
    echo "Process done";
}

func_get_proc_pids() {
    pids="";
    OIFS=$IFS;
    IFS='\n';
    for pidline in $(ps -A -opid -ocomm -oargs | grep "$1" | grep -v grep); do
        pids="$pids ${pidline%%\ *}";
    done;
    IFS=$OIFS;
    echo ${pids};
}

func_stop_proc() {
    tailPid=$(func_get_proc_pids "$this_name start $command");
    if [ "_" == "_$tailPid" ]; then
        echo "No process stopped. The command has to be exactly the same command (parameters may be ommited) as when started.";
    else
        for pid in $tailPid; do
            echo "Killing pid $pid";
            kill $pid;
        done;
    fi;
}

func_stop_listening_to_proc() {
    echo "Stopped listening to the process due to the $1 signal";
    if [ "$1" == "EXIT" ]; then
        if [ -p "$pipeName" ]; then
            echo "*Restarting dummy listener"; 
            func_start_dummy_pipe_listener;
        else 
            echo "*No pipe $pipeName existed";
        fi;
    fi;
}

func_listen_to_proc() {
    #kill `tail -f $pipeName >> /dev/null`
    func_stop_dummy_pipe_listener;

    if [ ! -p $pipeName ]; then 
        echo "Can not listen to $pipeName, exitting...";
        return 1;
    fi;

    #trap the kill signal to start another tail... process
    trap_with_arg func_stop_listening_to_proc INT TERM EXIT
    cat $pipeName;
    #NOTE if there is just an end of the stream in a pipe, we have to do nothing 

}

#trap_with_arg func_trap INT TERM EXIT

print_usage() {
    echo "Usage $this_name [start|listen|stop] \"<command-line>\"";
}

######################################3
############# Main entry #############
######################################

this_name=$0;
option=$1;
command="$2";
pipeName=$(proc_pipe_name "$command");


if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    print_usage;
    exit 1;
fi;

case $option in 
start)
    echo "Starting ${command}";
    func_start_proc "$command";
    ;;
listen)
    echo "Listening to ${2}";
    func_listen_to_proc "$command";
    ;;
stop)
    echo "Stopping ${2}";
    func_stop_proc "$command";
    ;;
*)
    print_usage;
    exit 1;
esac;
```

Answer (score 4):

No.  You'll have to restart the command.

Stdio handles are inherited from parent to child process. You've given the child a handle to /dev/nul. It's free to do with it whatever it likes, including things like dup()'ing it or passing it along to its own children. There's no easy way to reach into the OS and change what another running process's handles point to.

Arguably, you could use a debugger on the child and start zapping its state, overwriting any locations where it's stored a copy of the current handle value with something new, or to trace its calls to the kernel, monitoring any i/o.  I think that's asking a lot of most users, but it can work if it's a single child process that doesn't do anything funny with the i/o.

But even that fails in the general case, e.g., a script that creates pipelines and so on, duping handles and creating lots of its own children that come and go.  This is why you're pretty much stuck with starting over (and perhaps redirecting to a file you can delete later even if you don't want to watch it now.)

Comment: -1 for not knowing. Do you know that it is impossible (you know how it works internally), or you have just never seen it done.

Comment: I know how it works.  I'm the author of Hamilton C shell.  http://hamiltonlabs.com/cshell.htm

Comment: Accepted, but could you please explain the alternatives? Is any sort of re-redirection possible? Why not? How can I temporarily suppress any output?

Comment: @nicole Hamilton And I am the author of the answer, that works.

Comment: most processes seem to have one handle to stderr though so I like the idea of using gdb and then "overwriting" its current handle...wouldn't help child processes I suppose...

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using the [reredirect](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/) program:

```
reredirect -m <file> <PID>
```

You can restore initial output of your process later using something like:

```
reredirect -N -O <M> -E <N> <PID>
```

(`<M>` and `<N>` are provided by previous launch of reredirect).

reredirect `README` also explains how to redirect to another command or to redirect only stdout or stderr.